# java.util.Timer -- how can i make it fire now (before its actual schedule)

Tags: java, timer

I have a java.util.Timer in my application, that fires at a certain moment. But certain events may happen that require that the things that are triggered by that timer should happen.

Is it possible to make the timer fire pre-term, so to speak?

Comment: Can't you just call the method with the desired functionality directly when the certain event happens?

Comment: Yep, I ended up refactoring that functionality into a separate static mentod, and just call it from the timer and other places.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements sound mutually exclusive.  Things happen according to schedule or as random events, but not both.

It sounds like what you want for those events that don't fit into a scheduler to be broadcast to a listener that can spawn off an Executor to process them asynchronously.

Comment: Not quite. A user can stay in the system for N minutes, then some logout logic kicks in. If the user left the system before that, we have to do that logic at that moment. One of the variants i thought of was firing that timer prematurely.

Comment: How does the Timer know that?  Sounds like timeout logic that means another event.  Have the logic in one class that listeners for the respective events can trigger.

Answer (score 1):

A [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) is a [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html), so you can execute it directly in a new Thread.

What you could do to "run immediately" is:

1. [Cancel the TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel%28%29)
2. Run the TimerTask directly in a new Thread
3. Create and [schedule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29) a new TimerTask

I'm not going to say this is a good design choice though.